# Do I need to call unlock() in the Boost thread function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have the following lines of code where I used C++ Boost thread:

```
void threadFunc()
{
boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_Mutex);
//some code here...
condition.notify_one();
}
```

So should I call unlock() function before the last line, like the following? What is the difference if I don't call unlock()?

```
void threadFunc()
{
boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_Mutex);
//some code here...
lock.unlock();
condition.notify_one();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No -- the point of the `scoped_lock` class is that the lock is tied to the scope -- i.e., when the `scoped_lock` object goes out of scope, the lock is automatically released. This assures (for example) that if any of the intervening code throws an exception, the lock will still be released.

Comment: Thanks Jerry for quick response. Then the question is: In Boost threading, the pair of mutex lock() and unlock() is pretty much useless because the scoped lock automatically releases the lock when going out of scope, right?

Comment: @tonga lock() and unlock() can be useful for cases where you can't use a scoped_lock (e.g. locking in one function and unlocking in another).

Comment: Thanks Angew for your comments.

Comment: @tonga: In fact, the mutex's lock() and unlock() are what `scoped_lock` uses to do it's job. For example, see the `lock` class in one of my [previous answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10110623/179910). It's probably not quite identical to Boost's `scoped_lock`, but a pretty similar idea anyway.

Answer (score 1):

No. The lock is scoped, so it unlocks "automatically" as it goes out of scope. See RAII.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization